# Keep input value after form submit (with a catch)

Tags: javascript, php

In PHP, if the text input "cmtx_comment" is empty, on form submit I show a javascript alert. After I press OK in the alert, the values entered by the user in all fields in the form are gone. **How can I keep the user entered values, without adding code to the value of the input elements** (something like `<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo $_GET['something'];?>">` ?

```
if (empty($cmtx_comment)) { //if comment value is empty
echo <<<EOD
<script>
alert('Please enter a comment!');
</script>
EOD;
return false;
} else { //if comment entered
do stuff
```

Comment: you can validate it in client side, instead of submitting right away: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Comment: @juanpastas w3schools is not a very good reference. MDN is better

Comment: What are you asking? If the field is empty you show an alert, after the OK the field is empty?! Is there a problem here?

Comment: and why do you want to keep that value if its empty anyway? that doesn't make sense. you want to keep an empty value? or are you referring to those other fields which are filled up?

Comment: @Ghost - the problem is that all fields in the form, not just cmtx_comment are cleared. Even those in which the user entered a value... You are right, asked wrong..

Comment: try to validate it using ajax.. or follow @Dave Chen's way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried localStorage and form validation?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return saveComment();">
    <input type="text" name="cmtx_comment" id="cmtx_comment" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("cmtx_comment").value = localStorage.getItem("comment");

function saveComment() {
    var comment = document.getElementById("cmtx_comment").value;
    if (comment == "") {
        alert("Please enter a comment in first!");
        return false;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("comment", comment);
    alert("Your comment has been saved!");

    location.reload();
    return false;
    //return true;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bquxknm4/)

On first page load, you are presented with:

> [image]

If you don't enter a comment, you get the alert:

> [image]

If you **do** enter a comment, you get a different alert:

> [image]

The page will then refresh (or post, simply un-comment the return true, and comment the location.reload), and you will still see the contents you posted the first time.

> [image]

Comment: No, the form is being validated on the client side. When the page is posted/refreshed, the data should still persist.

Comment: If the comment was saved successfully after validation process, if user again going to the same page, your localStorage values will be there in text box.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo $_GET['something'];?>">` is what the OP wants, but not the same thing. He's going to want to clarify if he wants the comment to be saved while he's typing (no click save), or on click save -- and whether or not he wants the comment to be persistent on submission or not.

Comment: ok @DaveChen But really good solution. @ user3002057 FYI, If you are following this solution, after you saved your comment, clear localStorage.